# AM 3+ socket mainboard with at least 64GB DDR3 support

Tags: motherboard

I am looking for a motherboard, which

- has AM 3+ CPU socket
- support at least 64GB RAM (128GB is better)
- DDR3 memory modules

From 32GB, there is a lot. For 64GB, I found nothing.

Comment: We need to know what CPU you plan to use. AM3+ motherboards can have up to 4 DIMM slots, so that means the CPU has to support 16GB DIMMs. Not many AMD CPUs have been released in the time since 16GB DIMMS became available, and very few 16GB DDR3 DIMMs came out to the market at all. There are 16GB ECC DDR3 memory sticks, but ECC may not be supported by your CPU.

Comment: `/proc/cpuinfo` has this: `AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor`.

Comment: Why would it depend on the CPU? It should see only addresses on the north bridge, isn't it?

Comment: AM3 and AM3+ CPUs have the memory controller built into the CPU and there is no more "northbridge" on the board. AM3 CPUs that were backwards compatible with AM2+ sockets could work with a northbridge on older boards though. I do not see any limitations about the FX-6300 maximum memory, but it does not support ECC and the qualified memory list doesn't have any 16Gb modules. You will have to find non-ECC DDR3 modules and try them to find out if they work.

Comment: I already have a motherboard, currently it runs with a 8GB+8GB+4GB+4GB confguration. That is 24GB and works well - except that the motherboard started to do ugly things (like power off - power on all the hdds, even on soft reset). I want to eject it from my system and buy a working one. And, if I replace it, I would also upgrade it. But, the important thing: another motherboard with 24GB DDR3 already works.

Comment: Well you should be OK with any other AM3+ motherboard with a 970 or 990 chipset. These boards almost always have 4 slots for DDR3 which can support up to 32GB of ram with 8GB in each slot. It's still possible that 16GB in each slot *might* work, but it's just too uncommon to find info about it online.

Comment: @Romen I want more ram. If I can put in 64GB, then I want to.

Comment: Nobody can tell you for sure whether that's possible for specific parts unless they have tried it already. The problem is that AM3+ motherboards are older than the 16GB DDR3 sticks. They have never been tested by the manufacturer or put on qualified memory lists. The only way to know if it will work is to buy the stuff and try it; Or find someone who did already. It's pretty likely that it will work, but there are no 16GB modules on the "qualified hardware list" so nobody can answer this question based off just reading technical specs or manuals.

Comment: @Romen Okay. So I buy a 2x16GB DDR3 RAM, and there is some chance that it will work with my current motherboard?

Comment: It must be **non ECC** memory because the FX-6300 does not support ECC memory. The motherboard just requires the memory to be DDR3, the CPU is the part that determines what the memory limitations are aside from being DDR3.

Comment: Okay! What if it won't work? I will need to buy a new motherboard, too. And we are at the question.

Comment: Check this: https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/970M%20Pro3/index.de.asp It says 64GB max RAM supported.

Comment: I mentioned already that most boards *probably* support 64 GB of DDR3, even if the specs don't say so it might still work. That makes it very hard to answer your question in any certain terms, but you seem to have found a board that does specify 64GB support. You should try and find the memory you plan to buy and ask which board is compatible with it. Non-ECC 16 GB DDR3 is quite hard to find, and maybe even harder to find *in stock*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Pick from this list](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/motherboard/#s=4,22&sort=-rammax&page=1&D=68719476736,2147483648000)

As @peterh mentioned, 970 and 990 boards (generally) support 64GB of RAM (ignore the ECS boards that list 128 GB, that's incorrect.) Since these boards aren't widely available anymore (due to their age and relatively limited popularity), a specific recommendation is pretty much useless as it's entirely dependent on what you can find on the relatively-volatile used motherboard market.

However, given the cost of 16 GB DDR3 UDIMMs, you may find it cheaper to just upgrade your entire platform  (either to one with DDR4 support or with more RAM slots.) Given the age of the FX platform, you'll probably get a nice performance and feature set bump along the way too.

Comment: Wow! You are hardware & google talent. :-)